# Fast and best way to transpose columns and rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, pivot

How do I simply switch columns with rows in SQL?
Get this :

```
        Red  |     Red      |  Red  | Green  |  Blue  |
Paul    xxx     12-01-2021  |    0  |    1   |   0    |
John    yyy     20-01-2021  |    0  |    1   |   0    |
Tim     zzz     22-01-2021  |    1  |    1   |   1    |
```

Into this :

```
        Red  |     Red      |  Type   |  Value  | 
Paul    xxx     12-01-2021  |   Red   |    0    |
Paul    xxx     12-01-2021  |  Green  |    1    |
Paul    xxx     12-01-2021  |  Blue   |    0    |   
John    yyy     20-01-2021  |   Red   |    0    |
John    yyy     20-01-2021  |  Green  |    1    |
John    yyy     20-01-2021  |  Blue   |    0    |   
Tim     zzz     22-01-2021  |   Red   |    1    |
Tim     zzz     22-01-2021  |  Green  |    1    |
Tim     zzz     22-01-2021  |  Blue   |    1    |
```

Thank you

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  And for reference, Python is not a database.

Comment: What you're asking for is called "pivoting"

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume your columns actually have unique names.  You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select col1, col2, col3,
       max(case when type = 'Red' then value end else 0 end) as red,
       max(case when type = 'Green' then value end else 0 end) as green,
       max(case when type = 'Blue' then value end else 0 end) as blue
from t
group by col1, col2, col3,;
```